# How to get all iterations of a loop to a text field in swift xcode

Tags: swift

First ever solo app attempt, creating a very simple basic app. Noob alert!
I am trying to get all iterations of this for in loop to the text field. Only the last value shows up whereas when printed they all show up. Any noob guidance is appreciated :)

```
@IBOutlet weak var shelfSize: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    
    shelfSize.delegate = self
    
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

@IBAction func enterTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    calculateCoursing()

}

func calculateSizing() {
    
    let shelfHeight = Int(shelfSize.text!)
    let veryTight = shelfSize! + 8
    
    for index in 1...10 {
        print("Course \(index) = \(index * veryTight)")
        
        textView.text = "Course \(index) = \(index * veryTight)"

    }
}
```

Comment: `textView.text! += "Course \(index) = \(index * veryTight)\n"`

Comment: wow! that was crazy simple. Thank you Leo :)